# how to change the value of the form in the preprocess functions or get the value of the function preprocess

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I need to get the value of preprocess function and write it in the form `#default_value`, while my form is a variable that preprocess functions
I create custom module

```
<?php
/**
 * Реализация template_preprocess_comment()
 **/
function comment_email_form_preprocess_comment(&$variables){
    $variables['content']['email_form']['email']['#default_value'] = 'New value!';
    $variables['content']['email_form'] = show(drupal_get_form('comment_email_form'));
    dsm($variables);
}
/**
 * Создаем форму, которая будет хранить данные email адресов бригад и отправлять письмо.
 **/
function comment_email_form($form, &$form_state){
$query = db_select('comment', 'c')
    ->fields('c', array('cid', 'nid'));
$result = $query->execute();
$comments = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $comments[$value->cid] = comment_load($value->cid);
 }
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'test123',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Send'),
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = 'comment_email_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'comment_email_form_submit';
  return $form;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass extra arguments when building the form using the `drupal_get_form`.

For example:

```
drupal_get_form('comment_email_form', 'default_value');

function comment_email_form($form, &$form_state, $default_value)
{
    // $default_value is here the string 'default_value' value passed as extra argument
    // ... rest of your form
}
```

Comment: but on the contrary I need to pass the value of preprocessing functions

Comment: In your preprocess function, where you retrieve the form, you can call show(drupal_get_form('comment_email_form', 'New value!'));

Comment: oh yeah, thank you, it works. very grateful for your help :)